# Get data of todays and 2 days before added from database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am currently working on a Laravel project. Now I need to fetch some data from the database within a period of days. I need to pass a parameter from the front end, like day =1 or day =2. If day = 1, then I need to fetch today's post. If day = 2 I need to fetch yesterdays and today's posts. I am tried with CURDATE() and NOW() and INTERVAL but I didn't get any solution. 
Please help me to do this.

[Code to fetch the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MV8dX.jpg)

[Table used to fetch data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQHFH.jpg)

Comment: Hi Gowtham, update your table(database).

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Hi Arun, How will I update my table

Comment: Please go read [ask] first of all. All code relevant to your question belongs directly into it, not just dumped on external sites or as images.

Answer (score 0):

```html
If you pass day = 1 then you can get today's post by whereDate laravel function.
e.g. pass day = 1
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$post = DB::table('post')->whereDate('post_date', $today)->get();
If you pass day = 2 then first of all you have to get previous date and get current date by date function and using whereBetween laravel function you can get yesterday and today's post.
e.g. pass day = 2
$from = Yesterday date
$to   = today date
$post = POST::whereBetween('post_date', [$from, $to])->get();
```

Comment: I have an issue With using whereBetween I only get yesterdays posts. I need today's posts along with the yesterdays' posts.

Comment: You have to passed yesterday and today's date in whereBetween.

Comment: $from = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-$day days"));
$to = $today = date("Y-m-d");

Comment: ->whereBetween('pinned_scribbles.created_at', [$from, $to])

Comment: pinned_scribbles.created_at is datetime or only date field ? please check your $from and $to data also check by passed static from and to date in query.

Comment: Yes, it is a datetime field. $from and $to are returning the correct value.

Comment: you have to compare only date from pinned_scribbles.created_at field. or you have to contact 00:00:00 in yesterday and 23:59:00 in today date.

Comment: I have to compare only the date from pinned_scribbles.created_at